# Proxy not detecting change on nested array

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, es6-proxy

Module code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

class database {
    constructor(database, object) {
        typeof database === "object" && (object = database);
        this.file = (typeof database === "string" ? database : 'db') + '.json';
        object && fs.writeFileSync(this.file, JSON.stringify(object));
        this.db = fs.existsSync(this.file) ? JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(this.file, 'utf-8')) : {};
        return new Proxy(this.db, this)
    }

    set(target, key, value) {
        this.db[key] = value;
        fs.writeFileSync(this.file, JSON.stringify(this.db));
    }

}

module.exports = database;
```

Example Script:

```
var db = require('./index.js')
var test = new db();

test.a = []; // Proxy is called here
test.a.push('a'); // It's not called here, despite test.a being set.
```

I'm expecting the `set` handler to fire anytime the object is updated, but when pushing to an array inside the object, it doesn't happen. Why is it not firing?

I'm using node v8.1.4. Supposedly all proxy issues were fixed after v6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, proxies can only observe changes made on the target object -- proxies cannot observe changes to other objects nested on the target.

`test` and `test.a` are two separate objects. So while `Proxy` will invoke `set` whenever a change is made to `test`, it will not invoke `set` whenever a change is made to `test.a`.

If you'd like to observe changes to an object and all nested children of that object, then you'll want to [use a library](https://github.com/ElliotNB/observable-slim/) purpose built for the job.